# How to read a file using offsets in c

Tags: c, structure, offset, fread

How can I read the contents of a file if I have to use the following parameters:

1. I have to read the file in parts by using "start-value" of the part and length of the part
2. The start-value and length of the parts will be read from another file

Overall, I am trying to compute the MD5 value of these parts (you can also call them as CHUNKS). 
The start-value and length of the chunks have been computed and stored in a file.
I tried to use `fread()` as follows, but it does not give me logical results

```
char *chunk_buffer;
//chunk_buffer is a pointer to a memory block 
while(cur_poly != NULL) {
    //cur_poly is a structure which is used to store the start and length of chunks
    chunk_buffer = (char*) malloc ((cur_poly->length)*8);
    //here I am trying to allocate memory based on the size of each chunk
    int x=fread (chunk_buffer,1, cur_poly->length, c_file);
    //c_file is the file to be read according to the offsets
    char hash[32];
    hash=md5(chunk_buffer);
    //md5() is a function which can generate the md5 hash values for the chunks
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `fseek()` function? I suspect that might be what you're after.

Comment: C or C++? Make those high-level project decisions **before** you start coding.

Comment: @Kerrek: It looks like stdio calls made from C++.  That's legal, and sometimes desirable from a performance perspective, although not the canonical C++ approach.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't mind stdio, [as you know](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h), but I do would like to know what language we're talking about. In C++ I'd use a less noisy and less error prone byte buffer object than I would in C.

Comment: Use of `malloc` makes C seem more likely to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Casting the result of `malloc`, and declaring `x` mid-loop suggests to me that it's C++.

Comment: `char hash[32]=md5(chunk_buffer);` — this doesn't work in C or C++ as far as I know. Array values can't be assigned, even for initialization. Is this some platform-specific extension?

Comment: @BenVoigt Casting the result of malloc is incredibly common in C code posted on SO.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you are right. I just added the assignment part now. Originally i was writting the result of md5() into a file. please check the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to note some more issues with that code. You might need to add some more details on these points.

1. If you want to read consecutive chunks from your file, you usually don't need to modify the get pointer of your file. Just read a chunk, and then read the next one. If you need to read the chunks in random order, you need to use [fseek](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fseek.3.html). This way you adjust the start position of the next file operation by an offset (from beginning, or end of the file, or relative to the current position).
2. You have a char pointer `chunk_buffer`, that you obviously use to store the data from your file temporarily. That is, it's only valid for the current loop iteration.
   If this is the case I would suggest to do the `malloc` once before you enter the loop:

   ```
   char * chunk_buffer = malloc (MAXIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
   ```

   in the loop you may clear this buffer using `memset` or just overwrite the data. Also note that `malloc()`ed memory is not initialized with `'\0'` values (I don't know if this is one assumption you rely on ...).
3. I am not sure, why you actually allocate a buffer of size `length*8` and just read `length` bytes to it. Probably

   ```
   int x = fread (chunk_buffer, SIZE_OF_ITEM, THIS_CHUNK_SIZE, c_file);
   ```

   would fit your needs closer, if your items are indeed larger than a byte.
4. It is unclear, what the `md5()` function actually does. What value does it return? A pointer to a buffer that is allocated dynamically? A pointer to a local array? Anyway, you assign the return value to a pointer to a local array of `char`s. You might not need to allocate `32` bytes for this, but just

   ```
   char * hash = md5 (chunk_buffer);
   ```

   Make sure that you keep the pointer to that array somewhere you find it when the loop takes the next iteration. An array that is created statically in local scope of that function can of course not be passed this way.
5. Your `md5()` function. How does it know, what the size of a chunk is? It is passed a pointer, but not the size of the valid data (as far as I see it). You might need to adapt this function to take the length of the input array as additional parameter.
6. What does the `md5()` function produce, a C-style string (alphanumeric digits, null-terminated) or an array of byte sized unsigned integers (`uint8_t`) ?
7. make sure that you `free()` the memory you allocate dynamically. If you want to keep the `malloc()` inside the loop, make sure the loop always ends with

   ```
   free (chunk_buffer);
   ```
8. For us to help you any further, you need to define 
   a) what are logical results for you and 
   b) what results do you get

Comment: my md5 computation works perfectly.my problem is with the chunk reading code

Answer (score 3):

I see two potential issues.

1. What units does `cur_poly->length` represent?   You are mallocing memory as if it is a count of 64-bit words, yet reading the file as if it is bytes.   If the field represents length in bytes, then you are reading correctly, but allocating too much memory.  However, if the field is length in 64-bit words, then you are allocating the right amount of memory, but only reading 1/8th the data.
2. The code seems to be ignoring offsets.  (Or assuming all chunks must be contiguous).  If you want to read from an arbitrary offset, do a `fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);` before the fread.

If the chunks are supposed to be contiguous, there still may be padding at the ends to force them all to start on  an even boundary.  You would have to seek over the padding whenever the byte count was odd (.WAV does this, as an example)

Comment: cur_poly->length is a uint64_t type. And you are right  i am assuming contiguous chunks(all the chunks belong to one file)

Comment: these chunks are computed using rabin fingerprint and so all paddings are taken into consideration

Comment: It's not the type of `length` that matters, the question is what units does it measure?  Does `1` mean "1 byte" or "1 long word"? See my edit.    Also, since you mention Rabin fingerprints, are your boundaries correct?  Check for off-by-one errors on the edges.